# Deleting a record using Mongoose with Redux

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I want to delete a record in my mongoDB, when a user presses a button for the given record. For reference:

[image]

I have all my mongoose and redux code set up, but i get this error: 
[image]

This is my action:

```
//deletes a survey when user clicks button
export const deleteSurvey = (surveyId) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.delete("/api/surveys", surveyId);
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_SURVEYS, payload: response.data });
};
```

And this is my route handler:

```
app.delete("/api/surveys", requireLogin, (req, res) => {
    Survey.findByIdAndRemove(req.surveyId, (err, survey) => {
      let response = {
        message: "Survey successfully deleted",
      };
      res.status(200).send(response);
    });
  });
```

The list of records is being rendered inside a component based react component. I am importing my action like this:

```
import { deleteSurvey } from "../../actions";
```

And the call to the action is being triggered on the onClick event of the button:

```
<button
    onClick={() => this.props.deleteSurvey(survey._id)}
    className="btn-floating btn-large red"
   >
   <i className="material-icons">clear</i>
</button>
```

How can i resolve this error?

Edit: Component connect

```
function mapStateToProps({ surveys }) {
  return { surveys }; //returns the surveys reducer from the combined reducers
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys })(SurveyList);
```

Edit: New error message

[image]

Which refers to:

```
return this.props.surveys.map(survey => {...}
```

Edit: Fetching surveys from API

```
const surveys = await Survey.find({ _user: req.user.id }) //get all surveys for the current user
      .select({ recipients: false }); //dont include recipients
    res.send(surveys);
```

Comment: Is your component connected? and is the action mapped?

Comment: I don't think it is properly connected to reach the deleteSurvey action. I've added the code in my original post.

Comment: You need to add deleteSurvey, next to fetchSurveys: export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys, deleteSurvey })(SurveyList);

Comment: I am receiving a new error message. I've included it in my post.

Comment: Ok this means that the old error is now fixed, what's the type of surveys? because map only works on arrays

Comment: It should be an array. fetchSurveys retrieves the surveys from a route handler using the select function. I've added it to the post.

Comment: print the value of surveys out to see its type and what is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't connected your action to your component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSurveys, deleteSurvey })(SurveyList);
```

**Edit:** Your second error is coming from the fact that map only works over arrays so you need to confirm that `surveys` is an array which you can do using: `console.log(this.props.surveys)`

Comment: Thanks, i solved it! Turned out I was doing my routing incorrectly. I had to supply my query pararmeter with: ${id} and mark my route handler with async and await.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [React-Redux's `connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) higher order function to map the action to your component.

**Note: this is not how you should write your code and is just for demonstration**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteSurvey } from "../../actions";

const SurveyList = ({ survey, handleDeleteSurvey }) => {
  return <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => handleDeleteSurvey(survey._id)}
              className="btn-floating btn-large red" >
              <i className="material-icons">clear</i>
            </button>
         </div>
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ surveys }) => {
  return { 
    surveys 
  } 
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    //note that this code assumes deleteSurvery is a thunk
    handleDeleteSurvey: id => dispatch(deleteSurvey(id))
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SurveyList);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure how to properly implement this in my connect function. Why do you have "const SomeComponent" instead of export default?

Comment: This is just dummy code and not how you should implement in code. Ideally you should wrap your component with `connect` and then export as a container component.

Comment: Are you wrapping the component with connect in your dummy code? What do you mean by container component?